# disassemble the sentence to understand the word of "where"

Tags: grammar

Sentence：
Would you please put the book **where** it belongs？

Q：
I tried to disassemble the sentence to understand what "**where**" looks like. (see as bellow)

(1) Would you please put the book at the place.

(2) The book belongs at the place.

so, "where" = "at the place" = "at which"

Am I right？

ref. Grammar book.

(a) **Where = in/at/on which**

(b) And follow the example：

(1) This is the place.

(2) I was born in the place.

(1) + (2) = This is the place where I was born.

so, "where" = "in which"

Answer (score 1):

> [1] *Would you please put the book* [*where it belongs*].
>
> [2] *This is the place* [*where I was born*].

[1] is the trickier of the two, so I'll start with [2]

Here, "where" has the locative expression "place" as antecedent, i.e. "where" = "place"; within the relative clause it functions as adjunct of place. We can represent [2] as **this is *x*; I was born in *x*:** the "in" component is contributed by "where" together with its spatial function, with the antecedent determining the value of *x*.

[1] is more complex in that the locative antecedent this time is not an adjunct but a complement of "put" and secondly this is a 'fused' relative construction.

Here, the fusion entails the antecedent and the complement are combined or 'fused' into the single word "where". The variables can be represented as **put the book in *x***; **it belongs in *x***, where  *x* means "some place"